# Wordpress tinyMCE not returning path to selected attchment image

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I'm currently hacking my way through building a very simple Wordpress plugin...

This plugin loads a TinyMCE button in the post editor toolbar and, when clicked, opens a dialog that asks the user to select 2 images from the Media Library.  When the user clicks to select either the first or second image it opens the Media Library modal where they can make their selection and choose which attachment size.

So far this portion works great.

Where things fall apart is when the json code retrieves the users image selections (the first or second image). Although the code below works 100% it unfortunately retrieves the path to the "full" imagesize and ignores attachment size selected by the user (in my case, "small", "medium" and "large" are all ignored).

```
window.mb.frame = wp.media({
    frame: 'post',
    state: 'insert',
    library : {
        type : 'image'
    },
    multiple: false
});

window.mb.frame.on('insert', function() {

    var json = window.mb.frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

    // json.url is fullsize image and ignores selected small, medium, large                         
    if (0 > $.trim(json.url.length)) {
        return;
    }

    $('#urlImgFirst').val(json.url);
    });
    window.mb.frame.open();
}
```

It seems to me that there must be an equivalent to:

```
json.url[imgsize]
```

...where "imgsize" specifies the attachment size url selected by the user in the Media Library modal).